# Nested multiplication

Tags: matlab

I'm having a little trouble with MATLAB code. Here is a function to calculate the value of a polynomial with `x` being the value to be evaluated at and `a` being a vector of polynomial coefficients.

```
function P=nesting(a,x)
P=a(end);
for n=numel(a)-1:-1:1
    P=a(n)+P.*x;
end
return
```

How can I modify the `for` loop such that `x` takes a m-vector as input, say, `x=(x1,x2,..,xm)` and the function is supposed to calculate every `P(xi)` for `i=1` to `m` and output everything as a m-vector? Any feedback is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with the current result of `nesting(a,[x1,x2,x3])`?

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps an extended comment rather than an answer to your immediate question, but here goes anyway.

Given a vector of powers such as

```
powers = 0:3
```

and a vector of coefficients such as

```
coeffs = [1 0 1 2]
```

you can calculate the value of the polynomial so defined (`x^0+x^2+2x^3`) at, say, `x==4` by calculating

```
dot(4.^powers, coeffs)
```

and save yourself those confusing loops.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`polyval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html) ?

If you want your own implementation than how about:

```
function p = nesting( coeff, x )

ex = (numel(coeff)-1) : -1 : 0;
v = bsxfun( @power, x(:), ex ); % vanermonde matrix
p = v * coeff(:)'; % dot product of coeff with respecting x^k
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it to a [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) as a systematic approach.

maybe the `repmat` and `cumprod` functions will help you.

Comment: `bsxfun` is much better than `repmat`...

Comment: I just found there's also a special command for the whole: `vander`